# Unordered list not refreshed after inserting data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have following code to display employees list from mongolab, inside an `unordered list`. Using ng-repeat it is listing employees correctly. Now I introduced a button to add new employees. It is inserting emploees records – but not refreshing the list in the UI. I guess it is because I am not using ng-model. My questions are:-

1. How is it displaying employees list even though I haven’t defined a model. Is ng-repeat creating a model implicitly?
2. What is the correct approach to add a model here so that two-way data binding will work?

CODE

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 //defining module
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);    

 //defining factory
 app.factory('employees', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/humanresource/collections/Employees',
                    {apiKey: 'removedmykey'}
                  );
 });



 //defining controller
 app.controller('myController', function ($scope, employees) 
 {
    $scope.empList = employees.query();

    $scope.AddUser = function() 
            { 
                alert("called");
                var d = new Date();
                var nameVal = "Emp-"+d.toString();

                var newEmployee =       {
                            name: nameVal

                            }
                employees.save(newEmployee);                
                return true;  
            };

 });

</script>


</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

     <div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>

        <li ng-repeat = "objEmployee in empList" ng-class-even="'light-gray'" ng-class-odd = "'dark-gray'" >
            {{objEmployee.name}}

        </li>

    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value= "AddUser" ng-click="AddUser()" />   
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-repeat` doesn't need two-way binding: it doesn't need to save anything from the view to the model. Two way binding is needed for input fields, for example: the input field must display the value in the model, and typing something in the field must update the model.

Your code doesn't display the added employee simply because you haven't added the new employee to the array of employees displayed by the view:

```
$scope.AddUser = function() { 
    ...
    // create a new employee
    var newEmployee = ...

    // send it to the server
    employees.save(newEmployee);

    // add it to the array of displayed employees
    $scope.empList.push(newEmployee);
};
```